# Simple TensorFlow LSTM Network: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I'm attempting to create a bare-bones, simple LSTM example to predict the next point in a sequence of floating point numbers. To keep things simple, I chose linear sample data. I'm using TensorFlow 2.3.1 and NumPy 1.18.5.

Here's the setup of the input data, a basic rolling horizon of length 5:

```
# Sample data -- linear function
linear_data=0.05+0.05*np.array(range(20))

# Size of window in rolling horizon
window = 5

# Tensorflow expects 3D: i,j,k = samples, window/sequence data, 
# features (one since we're univariate)
rolling_x = np.zeros([len(linear_data)-window, window, 1])
rolling_y = np.zeros([len(linear_data)-window, 1])

# Populate the rolling horizon data
for idx in [t for t in range(len(linear_data)-window)]:
    rolling_x[idx, :, 0] = linear_data[idx:idx+window]
    rolling_y[idx, :] = linear_data[idx+window]
    
print(rolling_x[:,:,0])

>>> [[0.05 0.1  0.15 0.2  0.25]
>>> [0.1  0.15 0.2  0.25 0.3 ]
>>> [0.15 0.2  0.25 0.3  0.35]
...
>>> [0.75 0.8  0.85 0.9  0.95]]
```

and where `rolling_y` contains the next item in the sequence. My understanding is that the data should be structured with the batch/sample data on first axis, sequence/window on the second, and number of features on the last (1 in this case since I'm univariate).

From here I build a really simple model:

```
# Build the model
tf_model = Sequential()
tf_model.add(LSTM(
    units=32,
    input_shape=[window, 1]
))
tf_model.add(Dense(units=1))
tf_model.compile()
```

It compiles fine, but when I try to train (`tf_model.fit(rolling_x, rolling_y)`) I get the following error:

```
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:756 train_step
        _minimize(self.distribute_strategy, tape, self.optimizer, loss,
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:2736 _minimize
        gradients = optimizer._aggregate_gradients(zip(gradients,  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:562 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    c:\users\____\documents\data_analytics\lstm-demo\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:1270 _filter_grads
        raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/kernel:0', 'lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0'].
```

Comment: You haven't specified a loss for training. I'm honestly surprised there are no safeguards in place for this. I would suggest to have another look at `compile` and the arguments it takes.

Comment: Such a simple oversight on my part, this did resolve the issue. I'll consider adding a feature request, as I assumed it would default to RMSE, MSE, or MAE. It could be more helpful in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned by @xdurch0, we have to specify the training configuration **optimizer, loss and metrics** when we compile the model.

Please refer [compile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile) arguments as shown below for training.

```
compile(
    optimizer='rmsprop', loss=None, metrics=None, loss_weights=None,
    weighted_metrics=None, run_eagerly=None, **kwargs
)
```

For the benefit of community here i am posting complete working code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

# Sample data -- linear function
linear_data=0.05+0.05*np.array(range(20))

# Size of window in rolling horizon
window = 5

# Tensorflow expects 3D: i,j,k = samples, window/sequence data, 
# features (one since we're univariate)
rolling_x = np.zeros([len(linear_data)-window, window, 1])
rolling_y = np.zeros([len(linear_data)-window, 1])

# Populate the rolling horizon data
for idx in [t for t in range(len(linear_data)-window)]:
    rolling_x[idx, :, 0] = linear_data[idx:idx+window]
    rolling_y[idx, :] = linear_data[idx+window]
    
print(rolling_x[:,:,0])

# Build the model
tf_model = Sequential()
tf_model.add(LSTM(
    units=32,
    input_shape=[window, 1]
))
tf_model.add(Dense(units=1))
tf_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=['mae'])
tf_model.fit(rolling_x, rolling_y)
```

Output:

```
[[0.05 0.1  0.15 0.2  0.25]
 [0.1  0.15 0.2  0.25 0.3 ]
 [0.15 0.2  0.25 0.3  0.35]
 [0.2  0.25 0.3  0.35 0.4 ]
 [0.25 0.3  0.35 0.4  0.45]
 [0.3  0.35 0.4  0.45 0.5 ]
 [0.35 0.4  0.45 0.5  0.55]
 [0.4  0.45 0.5  0.55 0.6 ]
 [0.45 0.5  0.55 0.6  0.65]
 [0.5  0.55 0.6  0.65 0.7 ]
 [0.55 0.6  0.65 0.7  0.75]
 [0.6  0.65 0.7  0.75 0.8 ]
 [0.65 0.7  0.75 0.8  0.85]
 [0.7  0.75 0.8  0.85 0.9 ]
 [0.75 0.8  0.85 0.9  0.95]]

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6889 - mae: 0.6889
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fa76e2b05f8>
```